# Iterate through files in a folder in order to make changes in Word Documents

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a plenty of word documents in a folder to which I want to apply style which I have customized.

This is my VBA-code. I want the VBA as like to go to the particular folder and apply the customized style to all the word documents. Any ideas?

```
Sub styleapply()
'
' styleapply Macro
'
'
    Selection.WholeStory
    ActiveDocument.UpdateStyles
    'WordBasic.ApplyQFSetTemplate
    Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sam'style")
End Sub
```

Comment: could you please tell us what you have tried?? there are a lot of examples which presents how you could iterate throughout selected word files. Did you tried any of them??

Comment: i am a novice to vba .. and as per my requirement i recorded the macro..and got the code as mentioned in the question, its does the job, but i got many docs so got loop the code through all docs.. in that directory..

Answer (score 0):

This should get you most of the way there:

```
Sub OpenWordFolder()
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim doc As Document
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = True
    fd.Show
    For Each folderItem In fd.SelectedItems
        fileItem = Dir(folderItem & "\" & "*.docx")
        While fileItem <> ""
            Set doc = Documents.Open(FileName:=folderItem & "\" & fileItem)
            Selection.WholeStory
            Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sam'style")
            doc.Close SaveChanges:=True
            fileItem = Dir
        Wend
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that I'm unsure if the ActiveDocument will have the custom style you've created - you may need to set the original document with the custom style to a Document object and then use that Document object to set the style for each file you've opened.